# Pointing to an element of a struct

Tags: c

I want to use the following code to copy the user input into a struct on the heap. I know it is incomplete but that's unimportant for my question.

```
#include "7.1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()

{
    struct Employee emp;
    struct Employees* emps[3];

    for ( int i = 1; i < 2; i ++)
    {
        printf("Please type in the emplooyes data./n Firstname:");
            scanf("%s", emp.first);

        printf("Please type in the emplooyes data./n Lastname:");
            scanf("%s", emp.last);

        printf("Please type in the emplooyes data./n Title:");
            scanf("%s", emp.title);

        printf("Please type in the emplooyes data./n Salary:");
            scanf("%d", emp.salary);

        emps[i] = createEmployee(char*, char*, char*, int);
    }

}
```

My question concerns the codepiece `emps[i] = createEmployee(char*, char*, char*, int);`. I don't know how to give the function `createEmployee()` the values of the `struct Employee emp;` as pointers. I know that's not necessary but i want to do it that way. I would be thankful for any advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
emps[i] = createEmployee(emp.first, emp.last, emp.title, emp.salary);
```

...but if you changed your function a little, it would be a lot better to use:

```
emps[i] = createEmployee(emp);
```

Your `Employee` structure could be defined like so:

```
struct Employee {
  char first[256];
  //...
};
```

...in which case 'first' is an array. Or, it could be defined as

```
struct Employee {
  char *first;
  // ...
};
```

An array of chars and a pointer to a char are very similar beasts. But in the first case, you will automatically allocate 256 chars for the first name each time you create an `Employee`. In the second case, you have to allocate the memory manually, and duplicate it appropriately when copying, and remember to delete it as well.

Say your `createEmployee` method looks like:

```
Employee *createEmployee(char * first, char * last, char * title, int salary);
```

If you take the first form of the `Employee` struct above, you might do:

```
struct Employee *createEmployee(char * first, char * last, char * title, int salary) {
  struct Employee *retVal = (struct Employee *)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
  strcpy(retVal->first, first);
  strcpy(retVal->last, last);
  // etc
  return retVal;
}
```

In the second case, you might do:

```
struct Employee *createEmployee(char * first, char * last, char * title, int salary) {
  struct Employee *retVal = (struct Employee *)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
  retVal->first = strdup(first);
  retVal->last = strdup(last);
  // etc
  return retVal;
}
```

Note that the second case makes deleting (and copying) quite tricky.

```
void deleteEmployee(struct Employee *emp) {
  free(emp->first);
  free(emp->last);
  // etc
  free(emp);
}
```

...but for the first form, you just have to `free(emp)`.

Comment: So is "emp.first" a pointer when i give it to the function or is it a copy of the original value?

Comment: @Ordo This may sound confusing but it's both. The "`first`" member of the `Employee` structure is (hopefully) already a pointer or an array (which is very related to a pointer). By passing `emp.first` to the `createEmployee` function, you are creating a copy of _the pointer_, meaning that it points to the same location. This means that any changes you make to `emp.first` the next time around the loop will be reflected in `emps[0].first` since they point to the same memory location.

Comment: Ordo: Well, depending on how you declared the data structure `Employee`, it's either a pointer or an array in `main` (and these are very similar anyway). Either way, when you pass it to your function, your function gets _a copy of the pointer_ - so inside the function, the function parameter is another variable with the same value. I'll elaborate a little above.

Comment: So everything inside a struct is a pointer? And why is an array similiar to a pointer? I guess all arrays are in fact array of pointers.

Comment: @Ordo: no, an array of pointers is quite different. An array is similar to a pointer because it holds an address - like a pointer, an array holds the address of an element. In C, arrays are arranged consecutively in memory - so you can work out the address of other elements of the array by knowing the address of the first element. But, because you declare it with a size, the compiler can allocate memory and do a few more safety checks for you. Not everything in a struct is a pointer - e.g. your `salary` member.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
emps[i] = createEmployee(emp.first, emp.last, emp.title, emp.salary);
```

You must consider that the `emp` data structure is local to your function (for this case `main`). This might lead to very weird errors if you're using `emp` anywhere else, because the data allocated for `emp` will be gone once the function returns - so using any data from emp, such as `emp.first` and `emp.last`, might cause some issues.

One way to solve this would be to also allocate `emp` dynamically, and pass a reference of it anywhere you want - this is usually how it's done.

Another quick hacky way would be to dynamically allocate the stuff that will be lost, such as your pointers:

```
emps[i] = createEmployee(strdup(emp.first), strdup(emp.last), strdup(emp.title), emp.salary);
```

[strdup()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) will duplicate the string you give it, and it will store it using `malloc()` (heap) so it won't be gone when the function returns.

Comment: I don't think you want `strdup`. If your struct members are char arrays, you want `strcpy`. If not, that `main` function shown has serious issues.

Comment: @sje397: Why would you need `strcpy`? `strdup` is for allocating the strings dynamically otherwise references are lost when the "main" function returns. Imagine this code being somewhere else other than "main" - can you see where the issue is?

Comment: You're assuming the struct members are `char *` - and if that is the case, the `scanf` calls are writing to unallocated memory in the function shown. If the members are `char []` however, then those scanf calls are ok, but you want to use `strcpy`.

Comment: @sje397, not really, I'm assuming they are `char[]`. That is static memory that will be gone when the function returns.

Comment: @Luca: The createEmployee function returns a pointer to a new `Employee` with char array members - so the memory is already allocated with the stuct. He has to `strcpy` into the new structure. If you pass in dup'd strings, he still has to `strcpy` but then also has to `free` what you passed in. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @sje397, when `emp` is allocated in the function scope (main), also the char arrays (first, last and title) are allocated. The data for those char arrays will only be available in that function scope (main). If you don't use something like `strdup` to duplicate these char arrays, the data will not be accessible outside the function scope. Does that make sense now?

Comment: @Luca: That's wrong. That data is valid for the lifetime of the `main` function. Passing `emp.first` to the `createEmployee` function is fine, because that function call is made _within the lifetime_ of the `emp` variable. It would be wrong to save those pointers anywhere inside the `createEmployee` function, and use them later when the variable has been destructed, but it is fine to pass them in and use them within the function e.g. as a parameter to `strdup`.

Comment: @sje397, I was just pointing out how this sort of thing is bad practice - I've stated in the question `This might lead to very weird errors if you're using emp anywhere else (other than main)`. Saying that this isn't wrong because it's inside main, sure you're right, but anywhere else this would lead to something bad.

Comment: @Luca: I'm not saying it's not wrong because it's in main - main is just another function. I'm saying, you could use `strdup` as you've described if the struct members were `char *` - in fact in that case you need to allocate memory. But you should probably use `char []` and there is no need for `strdup` if you do. And given the main function in the question, it's likely the definition uses `char []` - which makes `strdup` unecessary and a bad idea. It doesn't matter whether you're in `main` or not...

Comment: ...Passing in dup'd strings as paramters like you've done _requires_ that the function you pass them to saves them somewhere where it knows they'll be deleted later, or frees them itself. That's very bad practice, as the function now cannot be an isolated piece of logic any more.

Comment: @sje397, that's true about your last point. I did that because the user didn't provide the details of the function implementation - I was just showing how it would work and I stated it was `hacky`. However I'm still confused of your first point. Can you make clear why you think that `emp.title` would still exist outside the function scope (when the function returns)?

Comment: @Luca: in my answer there are two versions of the `createEmployee` function - the first with `emp.title` as an array and the second with it as a pointer. In the first case, the whole `Employee` structure is allocated on the heap, and in the second `strdup` allocates on the heap (as well). If we assume the struct uses `char []` then we use the first version - and you can see there that only `strcpy` is used, and that the function can be called from anywhere safely (not just main).

Comment: @Luca: If we pretend this isn't main, then the `emp` variable is a stack variable and yes, when the function returns it's data no longer exists. But, if we have used `strcpy` to copy that data into another bit of memory, that's fine. How do you propose the `createEmployee` method is going to store a pointer to data in main's `emp` structure, if the members are `char []`?

Answer (score 0):

First there is probably a typo in

```
  struct Employees // the s
```

You could simply pass the `emp` record as a pointer

```
  emps[i] = createEmployee( &emp );
```

And you have to allocate a new structure, that is returned to the caller

```
  struct Employee *createEmployee(struct Employee *p)
  {
     struct Employee *newe = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
     memcpy(newe, p, sizeof(struct Employee));
     return newe;
  }
```

Assuming the structure contains `char [x]` and not `char *`.

*Not tested.*